# How to turn an Excel Spreadsheet into a Database for PHP/HTML Menu Board?

Tags: php, css, database, excel, menu

I've been searching what I can, but coudn't find anything about Excel Database used in HTML/PHP/CSS/JAVASCRIPT website.

Actually, I found little information, but not what I needed, as I explained above.

So, to clear it up: I wanted an Excel file to be used as database for a menu board. If I could link it to a Google Spreadsheet or other, it would be great, so I can change information on the database and it would alter the menu board immediately.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a mini-example of how you can use google spreadsheet to save and access data in realtime http://jsdo.it/widged/gsheet_shoutbox (strictly browser based javascript)

Comment: There's not any real connection between Excel and Databases. They both use tables, but they're about as similar as Cats and Catfish... Are you familiar with PHPMyAdmin? That might get you close to what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you have been getting negative votes because it is hard to understand what you are asking for. As a non native English speaker, I know it really is not easy.  Do you want help rephrasing your question? If yes, could you paste the html for your menu?

Comment: some shameless self-promotion: one of my GH projects [here](https://github.com/ardkevin84/zf2-ims) has a thing you could snip out - it's a database model that populates an editable UI table. Editing a cell updates its db record by ajax. The route in that project to start with is /public/categories. If you want just the js that does it, clone [this project](https://github.com/ardkevin84/editable-table)

Comment: OK, sorry for not clearing it up. What I wanted was something like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmEQ9918wp4. He uses EXCEL to update the Menu Board.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is not a database...  Sounds like you're looking for an "Access" Database.  You can use Excel to add to/update your Access database with vba macros - the macros can even fire and update your Access database when you save your Excel file (or several other update events).  You can use the data in the database to populate the website data.  The topics you want to study are "Excel vba", "Access databases", and "access to php".  Hope that helps.

Comment: I think that by the mention of Excel needs to be taken as a request for a very very low tech  solution. Some easy way to store the file. Not necessarily a DB. A CSV file could possibly do the trick.

Comment: Please take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmEQ9918wp4 and, please, point me at the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: In the video they have a link to their website: http://www.eclipsedigitalmedia.co.uk/embed-digital-menu-boards/ where they're selling their specific usage of Excel.  My original answer stands.  They are using macros to update a database where the data is then published to various servers.  Cool technology, but there's a reason they are charging thousands of pounds.  This technology was not trivially created.